# React bootstrap with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting react-bootstrap to do it's thing in my react-redux app. I have a component that looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor( props, actions ) {
    super(props, actions);
  }

  render() {
    const { people } = this.props;
    return(
      <ul>
        {people.map(person => {
          return(
            <div key={person}>
              <li>{person.name}</li>
              <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={ () => removePerson(person) }>Remove</Button>
            </div>

          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

But react-bootstrap isn't styling the  element. Any thoughts on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: There is this not-so-visible comment at the beginning of the Getting Started section saying: `First add the Bootstrap CSS to your project; check here if you have not already done that`. I got caught, you ?

Comment: Yup that was the problem! Thanks.

Comment: made it an answer so that you can close it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this not-so-visible comment at the beginning of the Getting Started section saying: `First add the bootstrap CSS to you project`

I got caught,  you?